# Можно ли использовать Menu как ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Существует Menu, например такое:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Управление">
        <MenuItem Header="Прокрутка вверх"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Прокрутка вниз"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Прокрутка влево"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Прокрутка вправо"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Изображение">
        <MenuItem Header="Яркость"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Контраст"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Масштаб"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Поворот"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Могу ли я использовать его ещё и как контекстное меню без дублирования кода?

Comment: например, [так](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.PlayersModule/Grids/PlayersControl.xaml#L42)

Comment: Наверное мне стоит сформулировать вопрос точнее. У меня есть меню основное, но мне нужно использовать его ещё и как контекстное. Я хотел бы сделать это без дублирования кода.

Comment: вы это пробовали и что то не заработало или вы спросили ничего не попробовав?

Comment: Может быть я чего-то не понимаю, но в вашем коде я увидел, что вы вручную добавили два MenuItem в ContextMenu, чего я хотел бы избежать.

Comment: да, эти менюайтемы можно в меню добавлять или в контекстное меню

Comment: Я знаю, но вопрос был в том, что я не хочу дублировать код. Если у меня уже есть меню с менюайтемами, хотелось бы использовать это меню ещё и как контекстное **не дублируя его**.

Comment: в принципе Menu вставить внутрь контекстного меню можно, но выглядеть это будет странно :) Я бы думал в сторону, как переиспользовать не меню, а MenuItems

Comment: Я надеялся, что можно как-то подключить его, например через какое-нибудь присоединённое свойство, чтобы айтемы отображались и в контекстном. Пока решил просто скопировать их в контекстное меню из обычного.

Comment: @tym32167 `MenuItem` - тот же контрол, т. е. соответственно может быть только в одном месте в дереве. Лучше уж попробовать как-то шаблонами это генерировать.

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну я имел ввиду не MenuItem, а все внутренние MenuItems, то есть сделать какую коллецию менюшек и забиндить их на ItemSource менюшек или шаблонами. Но имхо, если это надо только в 1 месте, то проще копипастой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно собрать хедеры менюитемов в список (в данном случае, по всей видимости, это будет `List<List<string>>`) и назначить его итемсурсом для меню и контекстного меню, таким образом избежав дублирования в xaml-е.